# Supabase many-to-many join issue with dart

Tags: postgresql, flutter, dart, supabase, supabase-database

I'm trying to get the mentioned many-to-many join feature to work as described here: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/api/joins-and-nesting#many-to-many-joins

I have three simple tables:

```sql
create table parties (
  id uuid primary key,
  name text not null
);

create table users (
  id uuid not null references auth.users on delete cascade,
  phone_number text,

  primary key (id)
);

create table parties_members (
  party_id uuid not null references parties on delete cascade,
  user_id uuid not null references users on delete cascade
);

alter table parties_members add primary key (party_id, user_id);
```

I'm now trying create a query that joins `parties` with `users` but I get a: `Could not find a relationship between 'parties' and 'users' in the schema cache, code: PGRST200`

```dart
try {
  var parties = await supabase.from("parties").select('''
    id,
    parties_members(*)
  ''');

  var users = await supabase.from("users").select('''
    id,
    parties_members(*)
  ''');

  log("parties with join table: $parties");
  log("users with join table: $users");

  var partiesWithUsers = await supabase.from("parties").select('''
    id,
    users(*)
  ''');
} catch (e, stacktrace) {
  log("Error fetching parties", error: e, stackTrace: stacktrace);
}
```

The first two joins work... so it seems the references from either side are discovered, it just can't make the jump using the join table.

```
[log] parties with join table: [{id: b6e10467-7d1f-4705-8bb5-b59484c86955, parties_members: [{party_id: b6e10467-7d1f-4705-8bb5-b59484c86955, user_id: 48d4a132-46f1-439a-94b3-3ecb49d98a49}]}]
[log] users with join table: [{id: 48d4a132-46f1-439a-94b3-3ecb49d98a49, parties_members: {party_id: b6e10467-7d1f-4705-8bb5-b59484c86955, user_id: 48d4a132-46f1-439a-94b3-3ecb49d98a49}}]
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Using: `supabase_flutter: ^1.8.1`

Comment: I currently "solved" it with a view.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing the primary key constraint on your parties_members table.  You can create a composite primary key like this to complete the definition of a many to many relationship.

```sql
create table parties_members (
  party_id uuid not null references parties on delete cascade,
  user_id uuid not null references users on delete cascade,
  primary key(party_id, user_id)
);
```

Comment: I have that... it just wasn't there in the initial table creation, but there's a migration that contained ```alter table parties_members add primary key (party_id, user_id);```

Comment: I extended the question to include that, I have a pgTap test that ensures that every table has a PK, to ensure the Supabase Table Viewers work properly ```select has_pk(tablename, tablename || ' has a primary key')
from pg_tables where schemaname = 'public';```

Comment: @RanilWijeyratne Hmm, in that case everything looks fine, and it might be a glitch on your instance. Would you reach out to Supabase support about this and one of us can take a look at your instance to see what is going on. https://app.supabase.com/support/new